# SharePoint 2010 issue - can I create a bullet list that isn't double spaced?

Tags: 2010, formatting

I have some pages being created in SharePoint 2010 (we are migrating to 2016 next year, so skipping 2013 completely).

I can copy and paste bullet lists into the page, or create my own, but they all seem to double space.  Is there a way to fix this?

I have tried shift-enter, but that removes the bullets, and when attempting to put them back in via the bullet list on the page editor, they come out off tab, and wrong sized.  (No matter what I try).

Is there a work around, or am I stuck with double-spacing for this?  (The HTML editor is horrific and everything is jumbled into one big mess when I try to look at it.)

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you have to view the source. Copy the contents and past it to a real editor (such as Notepad++) and edit it there. When done, copy and paste back to your source view of SharePoint.

Comment: That's what I was thinking I'd have to do, was hoping for a work around.

Thanks!